# Django best practiche to know user id logged in outside the view.py

Tags: python, django, cookies

In my django project i need to know the user id logged in my pp.
I wrote a client/server application, many user connect with different username/permission on it, i would to know outside the view.py on every single client what is the user id connected.
I try to store a cookie after login on client in my view.py like this:

```
u_id = False
try:
    u_id = request.COOKIES['uid']
except Exception:
    response.set_cookie('uid', value=request.user.id, max_age=None)
```

but after this i don't know how retrive uid from every single client.
I try to inspect the django_session table but i don't know how can i link sessionid on client cookie to session_key on table for know what is the user.

Some one have an idea about who it's the best practice for know in every place of my app the user-id logged in?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of users currently logged in?

Comment: Hi, no i am try to have the single user currently logged in for any client. for example in my file store.py i would create a function that if client1 launch it i retrive the user logged in on client1, if client2 call it i retrive the user current on client 2 ecc ecc